# Relation view is not available phpMyAdmin on wampserver 2.5

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying for a few hours now to turn on designer view/relational view. Before formatting I remember that I have had this tab without doing anything. My tables are stored on InnoDB engine.

I tried : http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/pma_config.php and http://www.w3expert.com/2008/03/how-to-enable-view-feature-in.html and many more no luck whatsoever

Comment: It might be simpler to install MySQL Workbench, that has a nice design mode. Be careful though, it has 2 options, you want the one that does not include a new version of MySQL with it.

Answer (score 4):

When mapping tables with foreign keys in PHPMyAdmin, you need the “Relation View” link to do so. However, in WAMP, it does not show by default.

No fret. To enable “Relation View”:

Go to the file `config.inc.php` located in `/wamp/apps/PHPMYADMINFOLDER/`
Add this line:

```
$cfg[‘Servers’][$i][‘relation’] = ‘pma_relation’;
```

And restart Apache.
You should now see the “Relation View” link after that.

Comment: I don't know why they did this to wamp but thank you! This answered my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Open table where you want to relation and change "Storage Engine" to "InnoDB" by "Operation" tab

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Relation View is not a tab across the top of the screen, it's accessed by going to the Structure tab of a table. With new versions, there's a sub-tab at the top:

[image: New relation view]

I believe this changed with version 4.4; prior to that it was on the same page but a bit further down:

[image: Older relation view]

So if you're looking for a tab, that's why you're not finding it ;)

Regarding Designer, you have to have your "phpMyAdmin configuration storage" set up properly for the tab to display in the Database page. The official documentation is at http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage but basically you import the file `create_tables.sql` from the `sql` or `examples` directory of your phpMyAdmin installation, then you have to configure your `config.inc.php` to reflect the database name and table names you've created.

Have you successfully created the phpmyadmin database; can you log in with the control user and see the database and tables? When you log in, is there a message at the bottom of your screen that "your phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not properly configured" or some such?